# Recover published data in another page

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I have a page that allows you to publish something (which contains a name, a description, an image, etc.) and I am trying to retrieve what I publish on another page so that I can then manage it (modified, deleted, etc.) . But I can't really get this back.

When I launch it shows me exactly the same thing as what is in the page for published

I also tried to publish then after going back to the page but it always displays the same page as the other

[Post page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jujOt.png)
[New page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zFFX.png) (shows me the same thing)

```
FileResult file;
    NewTheoryViewModel theoryViewModel;

    public NewTheoryPage()
    {
        theoryViewModel = new NewTheoryViewModel();
        //activitieViewModel.GetItemCategories().GetAwaiter().GetResult(); 
        BindingContext = theoryViewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private async void Upload_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        shortcuts...

    }
    private async void Save_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TheoriesModel theory = new();

       .....shortcuts

            return;
        }

        var stream = ...shortcuts

        string fileName = file.FileName;

        theory.Image_id = imagesModel.Id > 0 ? imagesModel.Id : 1;
        theory.Group_id = 2... shortcuts

        var response = await Services.NewTheory.PostNewActivitie(theory);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Great", "The theory has been added", "Ok");
            await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

````
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode):

  var testPage = new SettingsPage
             {
                 BindingContext = theory 
             };

and at the top: public TheoriesModel TheoryPublished { get; private set; }

In the page where I want to retrieve: GetPublishedData();
     }

     private void GetPublishedData()
     {
         var newTheoryPage = new NewTheoryPage();

         // Attach an event handler to the Disappearing event of NewTheoryPage
         newTheoryPage.Disappearing += NewTheoryPage_Disappearing;

         Navigation.PushModalAsync(newTheoryPage);
     }

     private void NewTheoryPage_Disappearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         var newTheoryPage = (NewTheoryPage)sender;

         // Check if data has been published
         if (newTheoryPage.TheoryPublished != null)
         {
             // Use data published here
             var publishedTheory = newTheoryPage.TheoryPublished;
             // Do whatever you want with the data (display, delete, modify, etc.)
         }

         // Detach the event handler from the Disappearing event
         newTheoryPage.Disappearing -= NewTheoryPage_Disappearing;
     }
}```

```<Label Text="Published Theory" FontAttributes="Bold" />
<Label Text="{Binding PublishedTheory.Name}" />
<Label Text="{Binding PublishedTheory.Description}" />```


In other page : 
 ``` MessagingCenter.Subscribe<NewTheoryPage, TheoriesModel>(this, "TheoryPublished", OnTheoryPublished);
    }

    private void OnTheoryPublished(NewTheoryPage sender, TheoriesModel theory)
    {
        lblName.Text = theory.Name;
        lblDescription.Text = theory.Description;
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();

        MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<NewTheoryPage, TheoriesModel>(this, "TheoryPublished");
    }
}
````

and in NewTheoryPage:

```
var response = await Services.NewTheory.PostNewActivitie(theory);
      if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
      {
          MessagingCenter.Send(this, "TheoryPublished", theory);
          await DisplayAlert("Great", "The theory has been added", "Ok");
          await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
      }
```

I put the code with global static

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public static string Parameter1 { get; set; }
    public static string Parameter2 { get; set; }
}
```

Other page :

````
    {
        AppSettings.Parameter1 = theory.Name;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("access the value of mParameter1 : " + AppSettings.Parameter1);
        AppSettings.Parameter2 = theory.Description;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("access the value of mParameter2 : " + AppSettings.Parameter2);


        lblName.Text = AppSettings.Parameter1;
        lblDescription.Text = AppSettings.Parameter2;
    }```
````

Comment: have you debugged the code?  Does `NewTheoryPage_Disappearing` fire when the modal is dismissed?

Comment: Indeed, when I debug I do not arrive in NewTheoryPage_Disappearing

Comment: I would expect that to work.  But there are a lot of other ways you can pass data between pages.  `MessagingCenter` is one, or you can raise a custom event in the modal when it is being dismissed

Comment: What do you recommend, how do I do it?

Comment: I just gave you two suggestions

Comment: if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
         {
             MessagingCenter.Send(this, "TheoryPublished", theory);
Other page:
  MessagingCenter.Subscribe<NewTheoryPage, TheoriesModel>(this, "TheoryPublished", OnTheoryPublished);
     }

     private void OnTheoryPublished(NewTheoryPage sender, TheoriesModel theory)
     {
         lblName.Text = theory.Name;
         lblDescription.Text = theory.Description;
     }
I did that, but I also can't access OnTheoryPublished

Comment: Please add a new section to the question, with this updated code. Code is hard to read in comments, and having all the information in the question is easier than reading through comments. If you can't get the code to work, show the complete error message.

Comment: It's ok I added below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, it is recommended that you use the static variable.

For this, you can create a static global class for your app. And you can access and update these parameters across your app.

For example:

```
public class AppSetting 
{
    public static string Parameter1 = " parameter1";
    public static string Parameter2 = " parameter2";
}
```

Then in other places of your app, you can access and update your parameters as follows:

```
    //access the global variable 
    string value1 = AppSetting.Parameter1;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("access the value of mParameter1 : " + value1);

    //update the value of the setting parameter
     AppSetting.Parameter2 = "reset value for test";
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("the updated value of Parameter2 " + AppSetting.Parameter2);
```

**Update:**

I found that your code was misplaced.

If you want to use the static global variable, please remove the `MessageCenter` in your code.

You can try to modify your code as follows:

1.In `NewTheoryPage.xaml.cs`, change variable `AppSettings.Parameter1` and `AppSettings.Parameter2` as follows:

```
      var response = await Services.NewTheory.PostNewActivitie(theory); 
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        //MessagingCenter.Send(this, "TheoryPublished", theory);

        AppSettings.Parameter1 = theory.Name;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("access the value of mParameter1 : " + AppSettings.Parameter1);
        AppSettings.Parameter2 = theory.Description;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("access the value of mParameter2 : " + AppSettings.Parameter2);

        await DisplayAlert("Great", "The theory has been added", "Ok");
        await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
    }
```

2.On page `SettingsPage`,load data on method `OnAppearing`

```
   protected override void OnAppearing() 
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    lblName.Text = AppSettings.Parameter1;
    lblDescription.Text = AppSettings.Parameter2;
}
```

### Update 2

> It works at the beginning but, when I restart it disappears

The life time of a static variable is as long as your application is running.
If you want to save the data even after closing the app, it is recommended that you use [Secure storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/secure-storage?tabs=windows) or [Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/preferences?tabs=windows) to achieve this.

1.In `NewTheoryPage.xaml.cs`, save value as follows:

```
      var response = await Services.NewTheory.PostNewActivitie(theory); 
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        //MessagingCenter.Send(this, "TheoryPublished", theory);

        //AppSettings.Parameter1 = theory.Name;
        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("access the value of mParameter1 : " + AppSettings.Parameter1);
        //AppSettings.Parameter2 = theory.Description;
        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("access the value of mParameter2 : " + AppSettings.Parameter2);

       //save data here

       // Set value here:
       Preferences.Default.Set("name", theory.Name);
       Preferences.Default.Set("description", theory.Description);

        await DisplayAlert("Great", "The theory has been added", "Ok");
        await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
    }
```

2.On page `SettingsPage`,load data on method `OnAppearing`

```
   protected override void OnAppearing() 
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    //lblName.Text = AppSettings.Parameter1;
    //lblDescription.Text = AppSettings.Parameter2;

    string name = Preferences.Default.Get("name", "Unknown");
    string description = Preferences.Default.Get("description", "Unknown");
    
    lblName.Text = name;
    lblDescription.Text = description;
}
```

Comment: I did that (it doesn't change anything), but I put down the code that I added for you to look at

Comment: This is a global variable and there should be no such problem. Could you please post more code snippets so that we can try to test on our side?

Comment: Here is the github with the changes: https://github.com/Essama-Official/Fictum.git

Comment: Sorry, the code does not compile successfully on our side. You can debug to see if the value of `AppSettings.Parameter1` is correctly assigned to the `theory. Name` value.

Comment: When I debug I only access in Settings Page the line after InitializeComponent();, after it shows me the page

Comment: Then when was method `OnTheoryPublished` called?

Comment: Precisely I do not understand why she is not called?

Comment: The static global variable is ok. When did you want this method was triggered?

Comment: I have but the debugger here: AppSettings.Parameter 1 = theory.Name; and I tested further back too

Comment: You could debug to see the value of `AppSettings.Parameter 1 = theory.Name;`, right ? Is the value of `AppSettings.Parameter1` assigned correctly?

Comment: I can't debug to see the value of AppSettings.Parameter 1 = theory.Name;, I can't get into it

Comment: When do you want the method `OnTheoryPublished` to be triggered?

Comment: After that in New Theory Paige I posted something. So that afterwards I can recover it so that I can (edit it, delete it...)

Comment: It works at the beginning but, when I restart it disappears,

Comment: When I debug, lbl Name.Text and description are null now

Comment: Please check my updated answer at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: It shows me Unknown

Comment: You can debug to see if you have saved the data correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254457/discussion-between-jessie-zhang-msft-and-chris-curt).

Comment: I have small problems: It shows me that the news I thing that I publish and forget the others